# How to generate 16 bit LookUp Table for counting set bits

Tags: c, lookup, bit

I'm looking for solution how to generate 16bit, 65536 elements lookup table for counting set bits. I know to generate 8bit table i can use:

```
static const unsigned char BitsSetTable256[256] = 
{
#   define B2(n) n,     n+1,     n+1,     n+2
#   define B4(n) B2(n), B2(n+1), B2(n+1), B2(n+2)
#   define B6(n) B4(n), B4(n+1), B4(n+1), B4(n+2)
    B6(0), B6(1), B6(1), B6(2)
};
```

But i have no idea how to do that in 16bits

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to continue the sequence. Did you try that? If yes, did that work?

Comment: _65536 elements lookup table for counting set bits_ .... What does it means?

Comment: It's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/509868), but OP wants to implement it with a lookup table

Comment: I haven't got idea how to continue it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll just explain how that code works, so it's easy to extend it.

The LUT for 2-bit numbers can be calculated easily:

```
0, 1, 1, 2
```

That is:

- binary '00' has 0 set bits
- binary '01' has 1 set bits
- binary '10' has 1 set bits
- binary '11' has 2 set bits

Now try to build a LUT for 4-bit numbers. There are 16 numbers, which can be enumerated as follows:

- binary '00xx', where xx is any 2-bit number
- binary '01xx', where xx is any 2-bit number
- binary '10xx', where xx is any 2-bit number
- binary '11xx', where xx is any 2-bit number

This enumeration lets you count the set bits easily:

- binary '00xx' have 0+B2(xx) set bits
- binary '01xx' have 1+B2(xx) set bits
- binary '10xx' have 1+B2(xx) set bits
- binary '11xx' have 2+B2(xx) set bits

So your LUT for 4-bit numbers will look like this:

```
0, 1, 1, 2,
1, 2, 2, 3,
1, 2, 2, 3,
2, 3, 3, 4
```

In a general case, if you have your LUT for N bits:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...
```

You can convert it to a LUT for N+2 bits:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, ...
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, ... // all numbers as above plus 1
1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, ... // another row of numbers, the same
2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, ... // all numbers as above plus 1
```

The adding of 1 to previous numbers is achieved by the macros. To continue your table to 16, just add more lines:

```
#   define B6(n) B4(n), B4(n+1), B4(n+1), B4(n+2)
#   define B8(n) B6(n), B6(n+1), B6(n+1), B6(n+2)
#   define BA(n) B8(n), B8(n+1), B8(n+1), B8(n+2)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for explenation

Comment: @anatolyg: Thank you for the brief explanation. +1 I was about to edit my answer and add an explanation as well but you already did that (better that I would have done)

Answer (score 2):

I would say something like this:

```
static const unsigned char BitsSetTable65536[65536] = 
{
#   define B2(n)  n,      n+1,      n+1,      n+2
#   define B4(n)  B2(n),  B2(n+1),  B2(n+1),  B2(n+2)
#   define B6(n)  B4(n),  B4(n+1),  B4(n+1),  B4(n+2)
#   define B8(n)  B6(n),  B6(n+1),  B6(n+1),  B6(n+2)
#   define B10(n) B8(n),  B8(n+1),  B8(n+1),  B8(n+2)
#   define B12(n) B10(n), B10(n+1), B10(n+1), B10(n+2)
#   define B14(n) B12(n), B12(n+1), B12(n+1), B12(n+2)
           B14(0),B14(1), B14(1),   B14(2)
};
```

Comment: `char` cannot contain values in such a big (0 to 65535) range.

Comment: char is sufficient here, as it would only contain values between 0 to 16.

Comment: Nice,  Although I think I would use one more `define` and then `static const unsigned char BitsSetTable65536[65536] = { B16(0) };`